# Input xlsm excel file and get output in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, excel

I have a xlms excel file in which there are 2 spreadsheets, one contains a form of inputs and the other spreadsheet shows the output of these inputs (after doing some computation). I want a C# Application which give input to the spreadsheet 1 and get the output from the spreadsheet 2. I have Microsoft excel 2013 installed and using visual studio 2015.

I am unable to find any solution online. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better for you to implement the output logic in the c# program. It will require less time for you to develop instead of wasting time for searching a right library.